# Using Plugin to Insert HTML

Tags: event-observer, extensions, module, ce-1.9.1.0, footer

I am creating a Magento plugin/module which I would like to have insert html in various places on my site, such as for adding statistics in the footer - one version for the admin footer and another for the front end footer. The content itself is ready to go, just need to figure out how to get it onto the page.

However, I'm having a hard time locating a page that discusses how to use a plugin to inject dynamic content so I'm not quite sure where to begin. Still figuring out how Magento works, so any assistance/tutelage would be appreciated!

Do I need to create a separate template under the `/app/design/` directory and somehow trigger this (perhaps with an observer)? Or can the template files exist as, say, a file within my module's "Block" directory? 
I'd prefer to keep everything contained within `/app/code/local/My_Co/My_Mod/` if it can be done.